# Answers sorted by votes and acceptance

Tags: support, answers, sorting

When I view the answers to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89123/is-there-any-mechanical-race-in-lord-of-the-rings-extended-universe), sorted by votes, the accepted answer appears at the top, although it has only 14 votes, and the other answer has 24. Fine, that's what I expected, acceptance trumps votes.

However, when I view the answers to [this other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87979/story-identification-human-taught-powers-by-aliens-and-tries-to-save-the-univer) (still sorting by votes), the unaccepted answer with 2 votes is at the top, and the accepted answer with 1 vote is below it. **Why is that?** (In this case the user who asked the question accepted his own answer, but I don't see why that would make a difference.)

Comment: Presumably because it's self-answered (and self-accepted) at a guess...

Comment: That was my best guess, but I don't see why that would make a difference.

Comment: Dunno. Ask a mod. They should know the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because the answer on the second question was self-accepted. In this case, acceptance doesn’t trump votes.

Quoting from Meta.se, [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/226928):

> If you accept:
>
> - *someone else's answer:* You get +2 rep and the author of the accepted answer gets +15 rep.
> - *your own answer:* There is no reputation awarded and **the answer does not float to the top of the list**. This can be done no earlier than 48 hours after the question is asked.

Comment: See. I said that.